# How to change Google adsense font style

Tags: css, adsense

Is there is any way to change the google adsense font style and color using css?

Answer (score 3):

It's an option when you set up the ad. Otherwise it is against the Terms of Service.

If you really want to know, scroll down past all the people saying it is against the TOS on [this post](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum89/4871.htm), and someone has posted how they do it.

Answer (score 1):

you can change it inside adsense

Answer (score 1):

Point two of the [AdSense terms](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms) states emphasis mine:

> You agree to comply with the specifications provided by Google from
>   time to time to enable proper delivery, display, tracking, and
>   reporting of Ads, Links, Search Results, Referral Buttons, and Google
>   Brand Features (as defined in Section 12 below) in connection with
>   Your Property(ies), including without limitation by **not modifying the
>   JavaScript or other programming provided to You by Google in any way**,
>   unless expressly authorized in writing by Google (including by
>   electronic mail).

Doing so means Google might terminate or suspend your AdSense account.

Answer (score 1):

Changing Google AdSense Font Style is not a big task. Follow the following steps:
Step 1: Login to your AdSense Account.
Step 2: Go to Manage Ads.
Step 3: Choose your custom Ads.
Step 4: Change fonts, color, BG color style, etc.